# Is it possible to fire any function when text selected without mouseup?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a content editable div. So I need to call to a function when any text is selected inside of that div. Is it possible to trigger a function when text is selected by mouse and keyboard too.

Comment: I use this function, hope it helps :) http://jsfiddle.net/Lgbnzax8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DOM API has the `selectionchange` event for that:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/selectionchange

Unfortunately an even listener for that event can only be attached to the `document` object, and not to any specific element.

So what you can do is attach the listener in the `mounted()` hook:

```
mounted() {
   document.addEventListener('selectionchange', this.handleSelectionChange);
}
```

I've created a small sample project showing the usage. Unforunately the event target is always `document`.

https://codesandbox.io/s/kmxp4roz97

Comment: It's not fire any function. Is it a problem of Browser compatibility? or I have more events in that div so those events prevent that?

Comment: @ShanakaNuwan Check my updated answer. Unfortunately my first approach won't do anything.

Comment: thank you @connexo it's working.